# rails date_select failing when flash tries to display in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I ran into a snag that I cannot figure out what the problem is, I am sure its something incredibly easy to figure out but being new to rails I am stumped.

I have a nice little new.html.erb in one of my controllers that says enter some information:

```
<h1>Verify your Credentials</h1>
<%= form_tag(:action => 'create') do %>
    <br>
    <p>Enter your ID -OR- SSN:<%= text_field_tag "theID"  %></p>
    <p><%= date_select("dob", start_year: 1900, order:[:month,:day, :year]) %></p>
    <p><%= submit_tag %></p>
<% end %>
```

Fair enough, this submits to create as per the action in the controller where i do some validation (make sure they selected a proper birthday and filled out the SSN/ID).

So this is what I have

```
def create
    @userid = params[:theID]
    @dob = params[:dob]

    if @userid.empty?
        flash[:error] = "You need to enter yoru valid ID or your SSN"
        render :new
    end

    #yes I knwo this check is bogus, I really need to make sure its not a date from like today at least... 
    if @dob.empty?
        logger.debug "Made it to userid empty"
        flash[:error] = "You must include your date of birth"
        render :new
    end
end
```

Mostly easy peasy, I know the DOB check is bogus but what happens is if I put in no ID, and click submit or what not then I get the error :

`NoMethodError at /create_my_aaccount
undefined method '{:start_year=>1900, :order=>[:month, :day, :year]}' for #<ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:0x4afec50>`

On the line:

5

<%= date_select("dob", start_year: 1900, order:[:month,:day, :year]) %>

So not sure why it breaks the second time through after the render :new

If i really looked at the error it almost seems that the code to generate the flash might be malformed and making the error the second time through when the flash is trying to display (but I never touched the flash code from application being built originally by generator).  So yah totally stuck, and I know this is probably stupid easy to fix...just lack of experience.

`new.html.erb` :

```
<h1>Verify your Credentials</h1>
<%= form_tag(:action => 'create') do %>
    <br>
    <p>Enter your ID -OR- SSN:<%= text_field_tag "theID"  %></p>
    <p><%= date_select("dob", start_year: 1900, order:[:month,:day, :year]) %></p>
    <p><%= submit_tag %></p>
<% end %>
```

HTML Output of the view that breaks
(Caveat HTML output BEFORE the second render :new of the view cause that goes right to error)

So also should be noted, I can take out the date field ion the above erb and it all works fine... so maybe its NOT the flash message I dunno.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title> Myaccount</title>
            <meta name="description" content="Myaccount">
            <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.core.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.theme.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/assets/dataTables/src/demo_table_jui.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/assets/create_my_aaccount.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/assets/details.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/assets/emergency_notification.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/assets/home.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/assets/recovery.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/create_my_aaccount.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/details.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/emergency_notification.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/helpdesk_home.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/home.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/recovery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
        <meta content="w4HKsIXFvZU85/8Lfo2Sw1jdotohbNTaikD6y8lZ+fI=" name="csrf-token" />

          </head>
          <body class="create_my_aaccount new">
            <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
              <nav class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                  <a href="/" class="brand"> Myaccount</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>
            <a href="/users/sign_in">Help Desk Login</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

                </div>
              </nav>
            </div>
            <div id="main" role="main">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="content">
                   <div class="row">
                    <div class="span12">

                      <h1>Verify your  Credentials</h1>
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/create_my_aaccount" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="w4HKsIXFvZU85/8Lfo2Sw1jdotohbNTaikD6y8lZ+fI=" /></div>
            <br>
            <p>Enter your ID -OR- SSN:<input id="theID" name="theID" type="text" /></p>
            <p><select id="dob_{:start_year=&gt;1900, :order=&gt;_:month, :day, :year}_1i" name="dob[{:start_year=&gt;1900, :order=&gt;[:month, :day, :year]}(1i)]">
        <option value="2008">2008</option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
        </select>
        <select id="dob_{:start_year=&gt;1900, :order=&gt;_:month, :day, :year}_2i" name="dob[{:start_year=&gt;1900, :order=&gt;[:month, :day, :year]}(2i)]">
        <option value="1">January</option>
        <option value="2">February</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
        <option value="4">April</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">June</option>
        <option value="7">July</option>
        <option value="8">August</option>
        <option value="9">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
        </select>
        <select id="dob_{:start_year=&gt;1900, :order=&gt;_:month, :day, :year}_3i" name="dob[{:start_year=&gt;1900, :order=&gt;[:month, :day, :year]}(3i)]">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
        </select>
        </p>
            <p><input name="commit" type="submit" value="Save changes" /></p>
        </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <footer>
                  </footer>
                </div>
              </div> <!--! end of .container -->
            </div> <!--! end of #main -->
          </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: can you show html code of your view?

Comment: yess edited and added.

Comment: Hi Codejoy, I mean HTML generated code, not ruby code of view :D

Comment: LOL been a long day let me get that... good call I think i see where you are going with this extra set of eyes always helps.... let me vpn and get it.

Comment: Your date_select code was wrong syntax. Use this code for your view: `<%= date_select("dob", "birthday", start_year: 1900, order: [:day, :month, :year]) %>` . For your reference syntax: [date_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select)

Comment: okay let me try this, strange it works the first time.

Comment: hmmm "undefined method `birthday' for #<ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:0x3cb48b8>"

Comment: `@dob` now is a hash params, so it did not have method `empty?`. Also the date select is alway has data, so I think you don't need to check empty of date.

Comment: Well I was confused what the heck was coming back exactly in this line:    @dob = params[:dob]  but I have to say I had another logger.debug and the first if was the one triggering  if @userid.empty?
        flash[:error] = "You need to enter yoru valid ID or your SSN"
        render :new
    end so its going to new, not create again so the .empty (at this point) shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: so try remove the "birthday" in date_select: `<%= date_select("dob", "", start_year: 1900, order: [:day, :month, :year]) %>`

Comment: hmm is it trying to repopulate that widget some how (The date_select) I wonder if undefined method `' for {"(3i)"=>"26", "(2i)"=>"11", "(1i)"=>"2013"}:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess is griping that its not integers is that what 3i, 2i 1i means?

Comment: I wanna thank you for trying looking at that doc I cannot tell what I am doing wrong, unless the data in @dob has to be massaged before the render :new call somehow

Comment: omg after much gnashing of teeth I got it.  What sleep does for ya, will answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue was two (maybe three fold):

First:

```
@dob = params[:dob]
```

Is not a valid date, I had to do the following:

```
dob = params[:dob];
@bdate = Date.new dob["bday(1i)"].to_i, dob["bday(2i)"].to_i, dob["bday(3i)"].to_i
```

assuming my view had bday defined as:

```
   <p><%= date_select("dob", "bday", start_year: 1900, order: [:day, :month, :year]) %></p>
```

Then after that, it turns out the rails error message was quite nice telling me I had multiple directions..so I consolidated to this:

```
if @userid.empty? or @bdate.today?
  logger.debug "Made it to userid empty"
  flash[:error] = "Please enter a valid ID and select a valid birthdate"
  redirect_to action: 'new'
end
```

And I used a redirect not a render because it also stated execution does not stop and in the case of my create method the above code is in, I need it to on error.